# How to add values from 2 integer columns in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

Inserted data as :
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mathdb&precision=ms' --data-binary 'float_op_1,agentId=hell psatt=1.5,csatt=1.5'
Now if i run a select query with psatt + csatt I get 
panic: runtime error: index out of range

Answer (score 0):

This is a known regression bug due for a fix in the next release: https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/4046